# How /system/xbin/su works?

Tags: rooting, root-access

I used TWRP for installing the `su` command, and I installed `SuperSU` app from Google Play. It works.

The question - how `su` command works? It hasn't s-bit, so it can not change eUID. In what way it gets root's permissions?

```
shell@mako:/ $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)
groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0

shell@mako:/ $ su

root@mako:/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) context=u:r:init:s0

root@mako:/ # which su
/system/xbin/su

root@mako:/ # ls -l /system/xbin/su
-rwxr-xr-x root     root        75348 2016-10-29 22:31 su

root@mako:/ #
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking or what problem are you trying to resolve? su is the Substitute User (sometimes switch user) utility that lets you change the active session's owner to root. If you want to see how the executable itself works, why not look at the sample How-To code? https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser

Comment: I know, how to use it. I do not know, why it works. On linux eUID could be changed only by programs with 's' bit. On my Android device 'su' command doesn't have 's' bit, but it works. How?

Comment: Chainfires explanations: https://su.chainfire.eu